# How to select only completed months of data where date is in format YYYY-MM?

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

I have created a query to generate some dates:

```sql
create or replace temporary view dates as
   select date_format(add_months(now(), -2), 'y-MM') as date union
   select date_format(add_months(now(), -1), 'y-MM') as date union
   select date_format(add_months(now(), 0), 'y-MM') as date
;
```

If I run:

```sql
select * from dates
```

I will get:

```
#   date
1   2022-08
2   2022-09
3   2022-10
```

I would like to return only completed (whole) months.  E.g.

If `date_format(add_months(now(), 0), 'y-MM')` is `2022-10`:

```sql
select * from dates
where ???
```

Should return `2022-08` and `2022-09`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```sql
select * 
from 
   dates d
where
   date_format(d.date, 'y-MM') <= date_format(add_months(now(), -1), 'y-MM')

#   date
1   2022-09
2   2022-08
```